# Android Studio 2.2 by default doesn't show the line number

Tags: android, android-studio, settings

How do I modify the default settings to show the line number in AS 2.2?

Comment: This is a simple setting. But I always think that the default setting doesn't show the line number is really not satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio > Editor > General > Appearance:  There will be a "show line number" checkbox for Mac

Answer (score 0):

There's an easiest way...

Right clic in the left side bar of the Workspace area and choose Show Line Numbers (see pic example).

Enjoy coding!

[image: Android Studio Workspace area]

Comment: This does not set to show the line numbers each time AS boots up.